# iPhoto on Yosemite will not open

Tags: macos

On my new MacBook Pro, I have Aperture on Yosemite. I can no longer open iPhoto. The necessary upgrade is not available on the UK App store.

How do I restore iPhoto?

Answer (score 3):

If you've "purchased" iPhoto before, trash the old version and download the **current** version (9.6.1) from your Purchases tab in the App Store.
Edit: updating won't work any more (Apple wants you to use Photos).

PS.  I have Photos, Aperture and iPhoto 9.6.1, the latter I can download any time from the 'Purchases' page in (UK) App Store and launch/use it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but, if I remember correctly, the first time I boot into a (more recent) system which has iPhoto included and log into the App Store, I get coaxed into adding iPhoto, iMovie, etc. into my 'Purchases'.  Are you saying it won't work if acquired that way?

Comment: @Redarm only if you purchased the machine new. If you installed a retail copy of the OS, wiped the machine clean, etc. then those applications won't be on there. That assumed that you hadn't yet accepted the applications for purchase. If you have "purchased" them, then yes, it will work. Else, if they were originally on system but not purchased, and it has since been wiped/cleared/app deleted, you would have to use Photos or reach out to Apple Support to have them issue a DL code for the app. Sorry for being long-winded @_@

Comment: Thanks @smoooosher for the explanation.  I think we are on the same page now.  The OP seems to have ended up with an older version of iPhoto on Yosemite (I hope we agree).  So, because there can be cases, where iPhoto was included, but not redeemed, or otherwise added to 'Purchases' (which I did account for in my answer), it got down voted, even though it seems to be the only possible (legal) positive answer to the question itself.  I hope I got that right now.

Comment: @Redarm seems like we are. I'll go ahead and upvote due to the clarification. I can verify that the iPhoto non-purchase resulting in a dead product from my own case is what happens - if you don't accept, you lose it and it is replaced with Photos on 10.10.3 upon update. Speaks to the order which I do my software updates ;)